# How to remove first few bytes using filestream

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am using this piece of code to remove last 16 bytes:

FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs1.SetLength(fs1.Length - 16);
fs1.Close();

How to use this filestream to remove first 16 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

When writing to another stream,  etc,  skip those bytes.